# Can rrdtool store data for metrics, list of which changes over time, like, for example, top 10 processes consuming CPU?

Tags: rrdtool

We need to create a graph with top 10 items, which will change from time to time, for example - top 10 processes consuming CPU or any other top 10 items, we can generate values for on the monitored server, with possibility to have names of the items on the graph.

Please tell me, is there any way to store this information using rrdtool?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store this kind of information with rrdtool, you will  have to create a separate rrd database for each item, update them accordingly and finally generate charts picking the 10 'top' rrd files ...

In other words, quite a lot of the magic has to happen in the script you write around rrdtool ... rrdtool will take care of storing the time series data ...